# I'm using Brad Frost's 3-up Carousel, I'd like to have the panels loop back to the beginning when the end is reached

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, infinite-loop

http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/pgjav

As you can see, when the end of the carousel is reached the navigation button to the right stops working. I'd like the carousel to loop back to the beginning when it's clicked at this point.

I don't know if there is a simple solution to this, but I thought I'd ask. Any help, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value of `current` in prev and next functions.

Try this-

```
    $prev.click(function(e){ //Previous Button Click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(current>0) {
            current--;
        }
        else 
            current=animLimit;
        posCarousel();

    });
    $next.click(function(e){ //Next Button Click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(current<animLimit) {
            current++;
        }
        else 
            current=0;
        posCarousel();
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: Incredible! Thanks so much, I think this solution will do just fine.